# "At most one record must be returned by this subquery" Did I screw up with relationships?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Si I am new to acesss and SQL.
I have my little database (shop system) 
And I am trying to make a quite simple query where I print out the names of users and overall sum of how much they have spent.

```
 SELECT kl.name, kl.sname, Sum((SELECT onl_Sum FROM online_payment)) AS overall
FROM users AS kl, orders AS pas, payments AS maks
WHERE (((kl.Klnum)=[pas].[Klnum]) AND ((pas.Pasnum)=[maks].[Pasnum]) AND ((maks.paynum)=(SELECT paynum FROM online_payment)))
GROUP BY kl.name, kl.name;
```

I changed names a bit for it to be more understandable.

Problem is that is works if each user has only one payment, but when there are more than one payment from user it goes wrong.

Relationships are like this :
Users -> orders -> payments -> Online_payment
                            -> Not_online
Users can have several orders, but each order can have one or more payments ( problem) and each payment only have one online_payment/Not_online payment

I think I did screw up with relationships here, but I am not sure.

There are more tables and relationships, but there have not been any problem with them ...

Comment: Do you want to get the `SUM` per person..orr..?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kl.name, kl.sname, Sum(online.onl_Sum) AS overall
FROM users AS kl JOIN orders AS pas ON pas.Klnum = kl.Klnum
JOIN payments AS maks ON pas.Pasnum=maks.Pasnum 
LEFT JOIN online_payment online ON maks.paynum = online.paynum
GROUP BY kl.name, kl.name;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better using a Join to join your online payment and users tables here's an example i quickly threw together from my booking system database. You want to group by the user table Primary Key otherwise people with the same name will be grouped together

`SELECT u.Firstname,u.Lastname, sum(i.Total) as total from User as u 
Join Invoice as i on u.id = i.UserId
group by u.Firstname,u.Lastname,u.id`